# how to write entity framework query as like **like 'lap%'**

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I can't understand how can I write query like

```
select * from product where name like 'Lap%'
```

in Entity Framework

my **dbcontext** is

```
 dbFoodZoonEntities1 db = new dbFoodZoonEntities1();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
dbFoodZoonEntities1 db = new dbFoodZoonEntities1();
var result = db.product.Where(x=>x.name.StartsWith("Lap")).ToList();
```

Comment: after executing query i got line this result **System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[TestSite.Models.Product]**

Comment: Have you correctly specified the name of table ? May it is referenced with namespace ?

Comment: i got result thanks ,i miss some syntax but now work fine your answer is good.